# Unix while loop taking long time

Tags: bash, unix

I have written a while loop to read a file line by line.

```
while read file
do
  FileFound="`find $DataDir -name $file -print 2>/dev/null`"
  if [ -n "$FileFound" ]; then
    echo $FileFound >> ${runDir}/st_$Region
  else
    echo $file >> ${APP_HOME}/${Region}_filesnotfound_$date.txt
  fi
 done < ${Region}_${date}.txt
```

For 8000 records it almost took 2 days to complete. How do i optimize it?

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is off-topic for SO. Are you looking for a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Unix is not a programming language.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your loop is taking a *long* time is because it is running `find` 8000 times, once for each file!  That is really expensive.  You could run a single `find` for all files under $DataDir, store it in a file and then use it for looking up your files.  That would speed up your loop dramatically.